# How do i make it so that my figure automatically conforms to geometry margins via some command or other method?

Tags: floats, geometry, adjustbox

(Read before replying:) I will **not** replace the second picture with another example image, the point of this post is to show the problem that i faced when trying to use a real image.

i have the following code that has a figure lowered to meet my top margin parameter of my geometry dimensions which solved the problem that i asked about a week ago (being that the image went above the margin border), but how can i make it so that something like this is automated and is done without specifying that i want my figure lowered by .02cm?

```
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
    \cfoot{\thepage} % put the page number in the center footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
    \addtolength{\footskip}{-.5cm} % shift the footer down which will shift the page number up
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage[main=english,spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\newpage
\null
\vspace{-0.125cm} % This corresponds to the top margin set by geometry
\begin{center}
\parskip=0pt
\let\footnote\thanks 
{\LARGE \@title \par }%
\vspace{0cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the title and author
{\large \lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}%
\par }%
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the author and date
{\large \@date }%
\end{center}\par 
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the date and content after maketitle
}
\makeatother % ask if you want to change the spacing of the 3 top sections

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % this makes tables look better

\setlength\parindent{.5cm}
% }

\title{Title Random}
\author{David Patterson}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{1}. Introduction}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption*{Fig. 2: A random image.}
    \label{example}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{2}. Second Part}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
        \begin{adjustbox}{margin=.02cm}
            \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{04_figure.jpg}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \caption*{Fig. 2: A statistic showing the population of the Texas Horned Lizard, with it having a low distribution percentage in the Pineywoods area.}
    \label{Texas Horned Lizard}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

compared to the following

```
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
    \cfoot{\thepage} % put the page number in the center footer
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
    \addtolength{\footskip}{-.5cm} % shift the footer down which will shift the page number up
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage[main=english,spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\newpage
\null
\vspace{-0.125cm} % This corresponds to the top margin set by geometry
\begin{center}
\parskip=0pt
\let\footnote\thanks 
{\LARGE \@title \par }%
\vspace{0cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the title and author
{\large \lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}%
\par }%
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the author and date
{\large \@date }%
\end{center}\par 
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the date and content after maketitle
}
\makeatother % ask if you want to change the spacing of the 3 top sections

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % this makes tables look better

\setlength\parindent{.5cm}
% }

\title{Title Random}
\author{David Patterson}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{1}. Introduction}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption*{Fig. 2: A random image.}
    \label{example}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\textsc{\RN{2}. Second Part}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{04_figure.jpg}
    \caption*{Fig. 2: A statistic showing the population of the Texas Horned Lizard, with it having a low distribution percentage in the Pineywoods area.}
    \label{Texas Horned Lizard}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

and which resulted in

[image]

Is there a setting in `adjustbox` that might do what i need it to do automatically? the image that is in my example is this one

[image]

Comment: Do you really need all of that code to demonstrate the problem? If you remove the title and earlier image, does the problem go away? If you can't reproduce with a standard sample image, just use a box of the appropriate size or give `\includegraphics` the data and use `draft` mode.

Comment: as shown in the answer you could have demonstrated this using any image

Answer (score 2):

After reducing your example a lot to:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a4-numbered}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I found, that `geometry`'s option `showframe` seems to draw the top frame line of the text area *inside* the text area. You can very this also using:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\rule{.5\textwidth}{\textheight}}}}

\end{document}
```

Here a screenshot of the top left corner in with magnification 5000%:

[image]

Using package `showframe` instead (and moving the frame into background):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[noframe]{showframe}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ShowFramePicture}

\begin{document}

\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\rule{.5\textwidth}{\textheight}}}}

\end{document}
```

shows the correct result:

[image]

Back to your problem: With your example but package `showframe` to visualize the areas, I get:

[image]

So IMHO there isn't any problem, but an approach of the German saying: “Wer viel misst, misst Mist.” (In English: “If you measure a lot, you measure crap.”). In other words, the image is placed correctly at the top of the text area, so it respects the settings of `geometry`, even if the frame displayed by `geometry` suggests otherwise.

BTW: You're example could have been reduced without loosing anything to:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{04_figure.jpg}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}
```

and even to:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[page=1,width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a4-numbered}
    \caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```